# Rspec test Devise RegistrationsController with AbstractController error

Tags: rspec, devise, user-registration

Rspec config

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
...
```

Routes

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { passwords: "users/passwords", sessions: "users/sessions", registrations: "users/registrations"}
```

About SessionsController

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController    
end
```

Test code

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Users::SessionsController do

controller do
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    super resource
  end
end

describe "After user sigin-in" do
  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)     
  end

  it "change current_user" do
    sign_in @user
    expect( subject.current_user ).to eq(@user)
  end

  it "redirects to the user_root_path" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    controller.after_sign_in_path_for(@user).should == root_path
  end
end
...
```

This test passes successfully! But when I do `RegistrationsController` test the same way, I got an error:

Test code

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Users::RegistrationsController do

controller do
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    super resource
  end
end

describe "User sign_up" do  

it "change current_user" do
  post :create, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:register_user)
  expect( subject.current_user ).not_to be nil
end
...
```

Error

```
Users::RegistrationsController User sign_up change current_user
 Failure/Error: post :create, user: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:register_user)
 AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
   The action 'create' could not be found for AnonymousController
 # ./spec/controllers/registrations_controller_spec.rb:18:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Better show the controllers you're testing.

Comment: I created the custom controller, but I didn't change or extend any controller actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some mistakes to user method **controller** in `*_spec.rb` file, it defines an anonymous controller which inherit from the described class. You can also change it inheriting from **ApplicationController** by change the config in `spec_helper.rb`

```
config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
```

You can reference the link for more
https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs/anonymous-controller